# Google App Engine - Is it necessary to call self.response in handler?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm developing with GAE Python. If I have a URL that routes to a handler, is it necessary to actually call self.response.out.write or self.render(if I'm using a template)?

I'm thinking if I don't specify a response.out call, then the instance GAE creates to handle that request will stay alive so to speak indefinitely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your handler ends, the response goes to the client -- if you've never written anything to the response, then it will be an empty response (should come with an HTTP 204 status, but browsers are notoriously resigned to broken servers like the one you're apparently planning to create:-).

Nothing about this will cause "the instance GAE creates to handle that request will stay alive so to speak indefinitely". After at most 60 seconds (for auto-scaled modules, which are the default choice), things will time out and a 500 HTTP status will go to the browser.

Comment: OK thanks. I"m asking specifically for handlers that handle AJAX post requests where no data needs to be sent back to client. Is it acceptable to not write anything out to the response?

Comment: I have handlers for AJAX responses that don't bother with an explicit response. Works fine for my purposes.

Comment: Thanks @DaveW.Smith I was just checking if there were any potential issues from a performance/efficiency standpoint.

Comment: @JK140 if there's no response body don't write anything to the response, but DO follow the HTTP standard and give a 204 status -- it costs nothing.

Comment: @AlexMartelli Thanks very much. Apologize if this is a dumb question, but how exactly do I respond with a 204 status? I know for an error I can do self.error(404). Do I write self.write(204)?

Comment: @JK140, App Engine supports many different web-app frameworks for Python, and you don't tell us which one you're using. Assuming you're using the popular `webapp2` framework, `self.response.status = 204` would be the most normal way to set the HTTP response status to 204.